# Opacity of absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a popup box that causes the surrounding area to get greyed out. My issue is that the opacity of the shadow div seems to overide that of the popup. I tried changing one from absolute to fixed position and increasing the z index of the popup but neither worked.

[Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/88682337/cssIssue.bmp) is a screensot of the problem.

And below is the relevent code (ask if you need to see more)

```
.textPopup
{
    width: 1400px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: White;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 15;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
#innerPopup
{
    background-color: White;
    width: 1350px;
    height: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 15;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

... snip
    <div id="popupShadow">
    </div>
    <div class="textPopup">
        <div id="innerPopup">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your screenshot link returns a 404 not-found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is that `#innerPopup` is inside `#textPopup`. The opacity is then inherited by the child and cannot be overridden with it's own property.

If it is not possible to separate them, then consider using an `rgba` value for the background as opposed to the `opacity` property:

```
#textPopup {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

You can see it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/fC2Mz/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to make it work as expected by making the following changes in your CSS:

```
#innerPopup
{
    position: relative; /* change this to relative - will allow you to override the parent specified opacity */

    opacity: 1;

    /* other properties */
}
```

Comment: #innerPopup will also need a higher z-index than .textPopup will it not?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `position` is `relative` or `absolute`, the element is still a child and will inherit it's parent's opacity. Tried in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/fC2Mz/